# Replacing my old secondary HDD

Tags: hard-drive, cpu

For the last couple days my PC started to stutter every now and then, so I checked my CPU usage and I saw that the CPU usage would jump from 4-6% to 50-60% for a couple seconds every 20 seconds or so. After doing some research I found out that my secondary hard drive does not work properly and that is what is most likely causing the stuttering. Now my question is a bit silly but I would like to ask if I can simply swap the HDDs without having to change anything in the BIOS?
Note: This is a secondary disk and there is nothing on it that I want to copy on the new one, I just want to get a new disk with more space.

Comment: Why don't you confirm the HDD is the actual problem before you go to the effort of replacing it?

Comment: It's pretty old and hard disk sentinel says that there were a bunch of errors while transfering files. And a while back I got a windows allert that there is a problem with my hard drive

Comment: Try using the system without the secondary HDD to see if the problem persists if you did get an alert from windows the disc is most likely failing but to make sure run your system for a little bit without it and see if it runs better then. Decided whether you want to go purchase a new drive or not.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what type of connection does your PC uses? Or how old it is? (eg. IDE or SATA)
Old IDE has a jumper at the back to determine if it's master vs slave secondary HDD, most modern HDD uses SATA connections and you can just swap a new one without the need of additional configurations

Comment: It's an older disk but it's SATA. So I just switch the disks and my PC should recognize the new disk?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to just switch the disk and it would recognize it. Though, you might have to format and establish a new drive letter for the new drive though.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to change anything in the BIOS for modern SATA drives.

Disconnect the drive and add the new drive. It should show up in your disk management application. From there, you can format and partition the drive into whatever volumes you desire.